# Изменение кодировки

Tags: jquery, кодировка, javascript

Привет всем! При установке одного скрипта на UI JQuery, сразу нормальная кодировка, после внесения некоторых изменений в CSS файле, меняется кодировка сама. Кодировка самого сайте не меняется, только этого скрипта. Почему так происходит? Как это решить?

Comment: Дело в вашем редакторе. В зависимости от того, что вы используете, необходимо узнать как в редакторе указывать кодировку (при сохранении чаще всего). кодировка должна быть для всех файлов одна, лучше utf-8, про другие кодировки (типа win-1251) лучше забыть.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментария:*

Дело в вашем редакторе. В зависимости от того, что вы используете, необходимо узнать как в редакторе указывать кодировку (при сохранении чаще всего). кодировка должна быть для всех файлов одна, лучше UTF-8, про другие кодировки (типа Win-1251) лучше забыть.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно файл сохраняете в кодировке WIN-1251, тогда как необходимо сохранять в UTF-8.

Comment: У меня прогресс бар на русском. Мне соответственно нужна кодировка WIN-1251, как отключить, перекодировку в UTF-8?

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку для всей страницы:

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=WIN-1251" />
    </head>